# How to solve $y''+y=x^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to solve:

$$y''+y=x^2$$

Taking the Laplace transform  (and using the fact that it is a linear operator) on both sides I get:

$$\mathscr{L}(y)=\frac{2}{s^3(s^2+1)}+y(0)\frac{s}{s^2+1}+y'(0)\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$

And hence:

$$y=2G(x)+y(0)\cos x +y'(0)\sin x$$

Where $G(x)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of:

$$\frac{1}{s^3(s^2+1)}$$

My question is how do I find this inverse Laplace transform, I'm used to splitting the fraction into partial fractions but I don't think I'm used to doing a partial fraction like in the above.

Comment: Clearly sines and cosines provide the homogeneous solutions. So now you want something with $y''+y  = x^2$; a kind of obvious choice is a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$; for this, $y'' + y = ax^2 + bx + (c+2a)$, whence $a = 1, b = 0, c = -2$. So the particular solution is $y = x^2 - 2$.

Comment: Solve $y''+y=x^2$ when $y$ is a polynomial, then solve $y''+y=0$ to get the infinite class of solutions to the first equation. The polynomial solution is $y=x^2-2$.

Comment: Laplace transform seems like overkill here.

Comment: I just learned it 30-mins ago so I'm trying to use it now anyways. @TnilkImaniq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the Laplace solution you asked for, you can split the fraction like this:
$$\frac 1{s^3(s^2+2)}=\frac As+\frac B{s^2}+\frac C{s^3}+\frac{Ds+E}{s^2+1}$$
$$=\frac{As^4+As^2+Bs^3+Bs+Cs^2+2C+Ds^4+Es^3}{s^3(s^2+1)}$$
$$=\frac{(A+D)s^4+(B+E)s^3+(A+C)s^2+Bs+C}{s^3(s^2+1)}$$

By identification, you find $B=0,E=0,C=1,A=-1,D=1$

Comment: Thanks very much. This is what I was looking for I forgot about what to do with the $s^3$ part.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I have added more details...

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I **hate** the Laplace transform!  I have yet to find a differential equation that cannot be solved more easily using simpler methods.  Here, the differential equation is $y''+ y= x^2$.  The associated homogeneous equation is $y''+ y= 0$.  Its characteristic equation is $r^2+ 1= 0$ which has roots $r= \pm i$ so the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation is $C_1cos(x)+ C_2sin(x)$.  The right hand side, $x^2$, is one of the kinds of functions we would expect as a solution to such an equation so we use "undetermined coefficients"- try $y= Ax^2+ Bx+ C$ for constants A, B, C to be determined.  Then $y'= 2Ax+ B$ and $y''= 2A$.  $y''+ y= 2A+ Ax^2+ Bx+ C= Ax^2+ Bx+ 2A+ C= x^2$.  Two polynomials will be equal **for all x** if and only if "corresponding coefficients" are equal- we must have $A= 1$, $B= 0$, and $2A+ C= 0$.  So A= 1, B= 0, and C= -2.  The general solution to this differential equation is $y(x)= C_1cos(x)+ C_2sin(x)+ x^2- 2$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{{1 \over s^{3}\pars{s^{2} + 1}} :\ ?}$

1. For the $\ds{\color{#f00}{\mbox{pole at}\ s = 0}}$, the residue is given by
   \begin{align}
   {1 \over 2!}\,\lim_{s \to 0}\,\totald[2]{}{s}\bracks{%
   {s^{3} \over s^{3}\pars{s^{2} + 1}}\,\expo{st}} & =
   {1 \over 2}\,\lim_{s \to 0}\,\totald[2]{}{s}\bracks{%
   {\pars{1 - s^{2}}\pars{1 + st + \half\,s^{2}t^{2}}}}
   \\[4mm] & =
   \color{#f00}{-1 + \half\,t^{2}}
   \end{align}
2. For the $\ds{\color{#f00}{\mbox{poles at}\ s = \pm\ic}}$, the residue is given by
   \begin{align}
   \left.\pars{s \pm \ic}{\expo{st} \over s^{3}\pars{s - \ic}\pars{s + \ic}}
   \right\vert_{\ s\ \to\ \pm\ic} & =
   {\expo{\pm\ic t} \over \pm\ic\pars{\mp\ic\ \mp\ \ic}} =
   \color{#f00}{\half\,\expo{\pm\ic t}}
   \end{align}

   > The final result becomes:
   >   $$
   > \pars{-1 + \half\,t^{2}} + \pars{\half\,\expo{\ic t}} + \pars{\half\,\expo{-\ic t}}
   > =
   > \color{#f00}{-1 + \half\,t^{2} + \cos\pars{t}}
   > $$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how do I find this inverse Laplace transform of $\dfrac{1}{s^3(s^2+1)}$?

**Hint**. *If one wants to proceed on your route*, by a partial fraction decomposition, one has
$$
\frac{1}{s^3(s^2+1)}=-\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^3}+\frac{s}{1+s^2}
$$ giving
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^3(s^2+1)}\right)(t)=-1+\frac{t^2}2+\cos t
$$ using standard properties of the [inverse Laplace transform](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).

Comment: @Felix Marin typo edited. Good catch! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.